# Checking for Duplicate value in list of multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So in my web application I am using BeginCollectionItems and it is working great. I can save my lists to the database and vise versus. My next step is within these list I'd like to check and make sure the collection contains Unique ID's. I could care less if the names are the same as it is common for people to have the same first and last name.

I have an individual user object:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid ID.")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a IEnumerable object of

```
public IEnumerable<User> UserList { get; set; }
```

I was looking into creating a custom validation attribute.

Something similar to

```
[Unique("ID", ErrorMessage= "You cannot use an ID that already exists in the list.")]
public IEnumerable<User> UserList { get; set; }
```

Essentially, it would check the list and look at the ID field in particular and make sure it is a unique ID. I just don't know how to approach it.

I would like to use this with other collections and perhaps check multiple fields within a list like an address list and make sure there are no two addresses with the same street, city, and state. That's diving a little further in though.

Comment: You could use a `HashSet`.

Comment: @Abion47 He must* :). In addition, you need to override equals and gethashcode methods.

Comment: Try this : List<int> intsA = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            if (intsA == intsA.Distinct())
            {
            }